# Passing arguments to Google graph javascripts

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script.Right now i am trying to build graphs with Google Charts. I want to  pass a structure to the script and get the graph.The structure would contain the  data,title,height,width etc.
Can anyone help me how do i build and pass this structure...?

Answer (score 0):

The Google documentation for [Google Chart Tools: Using Charts: Customizing Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts.html) shows how to do this, and provides examples.